# Class Dimension for java on android

Tags: java, android, dimensions

What is the equivalent form of class `java.awt.Dimension` for android?

Comment: Do you mean java swing Dimension class equivivalent? Single line question may not get helpful answer. Please provide as much information as you can.

Comment: yeah !! its the java swing Dimension class equivalent

Answer (score 15):

You can choose one of these options:

1. `android.util.Size` (since API 21).  It has `getWidth()` and `getHeight()`, but note it's immutable, meaning that once created you can't modify it (only create new, updated instances).
2. `android.graphics.Rect`.  It has `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` but they're based on internal `left`, `top`, `right`, `bottom` and may seem bloated with all its extra variables and utility methods.
3. `android.graphics.Point` which is a plain container, but the name is not right and it's main members are called `x` and `y` which isn't ideal for sizing.   **However**, this seems to be the class to use/abuse when getting display width and height from the Android framework itself as seen here:

   ```
   Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
   Point size = new Point();
   display.getSize(size);
   int width = size.x;
   int height = size.y;
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Pair<Integer, Integer>`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Pair.html) which is Android's generic tuple class. (You would need to replace `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` with `first` and `second`, though.) In other places of the Android API the Android team seems to use ad-hoc classes for this purpose, for instance [`Camera.Size`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Size.html).

Comment: Pair<Integer, Integer> will have 2 extra "new" for Integer boxing that will eventually need to be garbage collected. E.g. if you are using Dimensions in layout code and have a lot of view this is unnecessary additional burden on gc(). Instead you can implement Dimensions holder with atomic types and have a View data member holding it for the lifetime of the view and use it in e.g. layout algorithms w/o any boxing/unboxing and garbage collecting. The same way basic Android views are using temporary Rect[F] storage to avoid allocations. Added benefit is JIT can inline final methods - faster code

Answer (score -1):

Why do you need to abuse other classes instead of implementing something extremely simple like:

```
public class Dimensions {

    public int width;
    public int height;

    public Dimensions() {}

    public Dimensions(int w, int h) {
        width = w;
        height = h;
    }

    public Dimensions(Dimensions p) {
        this.width = p.width;
        this.height = p.height;
    }

    public final void set(int w, int h) {
        width = w;
        height = h;
    }

    public final void set(Dimensions d) {
        this.width = d.width;
        this.height = d.height;
    }

    public final boolean equals(int w, int h) {
        return this.width == w && this.height == h;
    }

    public final boolean equals(Object o) {
        return o instanceof Dimensions && (o == this || equals(((Dimensions)o).width, ((Dimensions)o).height));
    }

}
```

Comment: Because most programmers tend to forget to implement `hashCode()` and `Parcelable` and end up wasting precious time with such banalities when they could just have used `Point` provided by the fine Android API and moved on to more pressing matters ;)