# ClassNotFoundException for android/util/Size

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

My Xamarin app is throwing a ClassNotFoundException when I try to instantiate an Android.Util.Size object.  The error happens on my Android 4.2 device, but not my Android 5.1 device.  This leads me to suspect it has something to do with MultiDex, but I'm not sure where to start looking.

Comment: Can you show the code which causes the error? In particular, show how you are using the `Size` object after you create it.

Comment: Thanks Jon.  Silly error on my part.  Replaced it with Android.Gms.Common.Images.Size and now it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close, but it actually has nothing to do with Multidex(Good idea though!) It actually has to deal with the fact that this API was introduced in API 21:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Size.html

Thus it would work on Android 5.1 and fail on Android 4.2

Comment: How can the OP fix the problem? Is this class available in the Support Library?

Comment: I would say the OP can use `android.graphics.Rect` or `android.graphics.Point` on Pre-Lollipop devices (< API 21): http://stackoverflow.com/a/29094229/1048571

Comment: Of course that depends on how the OP is using `Size`. If he is passing it to a method that is only available in >= API 21, `Rect` or `Point` won't be helpful. Even so, you can improve your answer by showing how to do this. In particular, show how to test the API level.

Comment: I will update the answer if the question changes. I cannot really offer code help without seeing what they are doing.